# Windows 7 not shown in GRUB menu after dual boot Linux Mint 18.3

Tags: windows-7, mint

I made clean install of Windows 7, left some space unallocated on SSD and during subsequent Mint 18.3 install with default "Alongside" option did not got Windows in grub boot menu.

I write this mainly duplicate because the solution was simpler than in other questions I found here, see my answer.

Comment: @karel, I made clean install of newest Mint and got problem. The solution is simple and in such shortness is not documented in suggested link and IMHO is valuable to new Mint users. Fill free to edit or delete if consider otherwise.

Comment: @karel, I see my mistake, I will add my answer to suggested link, the question is indeed duplicate.

Comment: Karim Mokhtar already posted the same answer there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix/945988#945988. It's a good answer. Somebody should give it another upvote like I did. I read your answer that you posted here was how I knew it was a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran command below in Mint and Windows 7 was added to grub menu along with Memtest btw.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Thanks for the tip goes to more lengthy:

[Windows 7 not shown in GRUB menu, will not boot via BIOS, after Linux Mint clean install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671559/windows-7-not-shown-in-grub-menu-will-not-boot-via-bios-after-linux-mint-clean)

*Some developer, please add this to installer.*

Comment: Fair enough, I deleted my comment.  Thanks Alexei

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you [earned 15 reputation](/help/whats-reputation). If you have the reputation don't forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!